# UWP WinUI2 Xaml: how to show tooltip on disabled GridViewItem

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui

I have following Xaml

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ImageTextTemplate" x:DataType="local1:CustomDataObject">
    <Grid AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind Title}" Width="280">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="{x:Bind ImageLocation}" Height="100" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="8,0,0,8">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}" Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0,0,0,8"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Views}" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" Views " Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Likes}" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" />
                <TextBlock Text=" Likes" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<GridView
    x:Name="ContentGridView"
    ContainerContentChanging="GridViewContainerContentChanging"
    IsItemClickEnabled="{x:Bind ItemClickCheckBox.IsChecked.Value, Mode=OneWay}"
    ItemClick="ContentGridView_ItemClick"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageTemplate}"
    SelectionChanged="ContentGridView_SelectionChanged" 
    FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
```

And I have some items disabled using handler `ContainerContentChanging`. I want to set tooltip on those disabled items. How can I do it?

Things that I have tried -

1. Just setting tooltip inside the handler `ContainerContentChanging`. But it seems tooltip is not shown on disabled items in UWP apps.
2. Trying to handle `PointerEntered` event of `GridVewItem`. But once grid item is disabled, no pointer events are captured.

It seems `ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled` is not available. It was available in WPF. So how can we display tooltip on disabled GridViewItem in UWP?

Comment: Do you really need to disable the items? Can't you make them just look and feel disabled?

Answer (score 0):

> how can we display tooltip on disabled GridViewItem in UWP?

You can't do it in normal ways. Based on the document, when you disabled the GridViewItem, it means the user can't interact with the GridViewItem like focus, press and hold, or hovers the pointer over. Those actions are the normal ways to trigger the tooltip.

But you could try to do this by via the **ToolTip.IsOpen Property**. If you want to use this way, you need to manually control the time when tooltip is opened and closed.

I've tried to test in a button which is disabled, you could manually show the tooltip from the disabled button.

Xaml:

```
  <StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="TargetButton" Content="Submit"  IsEnabled="False">
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip>
                <TextBlock Text="This is the tool tip"/>
            </ToolTip>
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="Click" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToolTip tooltip = ToolTipService.GetToolTip(TargetButton) as ToolTip;

        tooltip.IsOpen = !tooltip.IsOpen;
    }
```

More information here: [Control.IsEnabled Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.isenabled?view=winrt-22621#windows-ui-xaml-controls-control-isenabled) and [ToolTip Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.tooltip?view=winrt-22621#remarks).

Comment: I was trying this way. But which event handler should I use? I was trying to set `tooltip.IsOpen` to true inside `PointerEntered` but this event is not fired for a disabled item. So which event can I use?

Comment: @rsp As I mentioned, you need to manually control the time. When the item is disabled, no input event will be triggered..

Comment: I need to know when mouse is over my GridViewItem and when mouse leaves that area. And since there is no mouse event that will get triggerred for a disabled item, how am I supposed to control the time manually? Any idea?

Comment: @rsp No ideas about that. Maybe disable an item is not very suitable for your real scenario.

Comment: @rsp Any updates about this issue? Is it acceptable for you to not make the item disabled?

Comment: Yeah, I am making the item "look and feel" disabled by using opacity value. Thanks.